# Atmel Zigbee home automation kit enquiry

Tags: atmel, zigbee, home-automation

I am looking forward to build a zigbee home automation system for which i require a zigbee module and its SDK. Atmel is one of the few vendors that provides SDK for download.
Could you please tell if Atmel kit  AT256RFR2-EK that acts as a wireless node in Zigbee networks worth its huge price?

Answer (score 0):

This site is intended for programming-related questions, and not for making recommendations on toolkits or libraries.  I'm really not sure where you'd go for reviews of the various ZigBee radio manufacturers.

If you want to do ZigBee HA, buy commercial products and integrate them.  The dev kits are targeting companies planning to build large volumes of product, and the up front cost of the dev kit is a drop in the bucket compared to hardware and software engineering costs.

If you're a hobbyist looking to tinker, just get some XBee modules and build a proprietary network.